# How to define what folder webpack dev-server (hot) should watch?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have a Node + Vue.js application, and in development environment I use webpack-dev-server for Vue.js.

But I want to set the folder that webpack should watch for hot reload, because webpack is looking for all the folders and I have a folder that webpack doesn't have access, that I use as volume for postgres's docker.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very opinionated question that has many answers, and no one correct answer.

Personally I would use nodemon to run your webpack-dev-server and add the folders in the watch options of nodemon.

Comment: But webpack-dev-server don't have any configuration to allow this? It already has a hot reload when file change, but there is any way to say which files it should watch for?